# list results from mysql on a listview in android

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I'm working on this tutorial, it's about querying the mysql database by using Json and a php script, and everything is just fine, but I'm working on listing these results you see here in a ListView and not as a TextView as you see below. Thats seems easy, but I can't make it work by replacing TextView with ListView.
image:

[image]

Here is the tutorial (code inside) :
http://blog.erlem.fr/fr/applications-mobiles/android/27-android-blog/applications-mobiles/android/59-android-connexion-a-mysql-a-laide-de-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All of the below assumes you have already parsed the JSON out into an array.  See [this for parsing help.](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)*

ListViews use adapters to grab the elements to fill the list rows up with.  You'll have to feed the JSON results into a SimpleListAdapter via a List or array (ArrayList, what have you.).

from [this page about listviews](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html):

```
SimpleAdapter nommes = new SimpleAdapter( 
this, 
list,
R.layout.main_item_two_line_row,
new String[] { "line1","line2" },
new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 } );
```

(in your case you could show/hide the id/name by using a one-line layout or a two-line layout like in this example)

Then apply the adapter

```
listView.setAdapter(nommes);
```

**EDIT:**

```
jObject = new JSONObject("<your JSON string from provider>");

// in my case: 

res = jObject.getJSONObject("results");

**dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.itemName);**

try {
  for (int r = 0; r < rslt.length(); r++){
    JSONArray jA = rslt.getJSONArray(Integer.toString(r));
    schoolLocString = jA.getString(0) +"|"+ jA.getString(1) +"[" + jA.optString(2);
    **dataAdapter.add(schoolLocString);**

  }
  **myListView.setListAdapter(dataAdapter);**
} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.v(TAG, "Exception " + e);
} catch (NullPointerException e){
Log.v(TAG, "NPE, no rslt");
}
```

This is a really lazy way to do it and probably bad practice, but you can get the idea.

Comment: thank you , but still cant make it work, anyway do you know any other ways to query an sql database and show results in a listview ?

Comment: I do it exactly how you are trying.  I make a php webservice that sends json down as a string which i make into a JSONObject and then can pull individual tags out of it.  If im using a listview, i add the results into an ArrayList and then hand the array off to an ArrayAdapter.     I am not near my workstation tonight but will put up a more detailed sample later.